# не могу понять в каком месте презентовать UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, alert

в приложении я отправляю GET-запрос на сервер, если приходит ответ, то я выполняю сигу:) и презентую его на отдельном `UITableViewController`. Но если ответ не приходит, то я хочу презентовать `AlertController` с сообщением, что по этому запросу ничего не найдено. Пробовал разные варианты и никак не могу добиться нужного результата. В основном получается, что когда ответ приходит и приложение переходит на `UITableViewController` вдогонку на этом `UITableViewController` появляется `AlertController` что ничего не найдено.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class DeclarationViewController: UIViewController {

let declarationInfoController = DeclarationInfoController()

// Alert controller for unsuccessfull load

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Нічого не знайдено", message: "Неправильні пошукові параметри або відсутні декларанти з зазначеними П.І.Б.", preferredStyle: .alert)
let tryAgainAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Спробувати ще раз", style: .default, handler: nil)

//       НЕ ЗНАЮ КУДА ВСТАВИТЬ СТРОКУ self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


var fetchedDeclarationInfo: DeclarationInfo? {
    didSet {
        print("FetchedDeclarationInfo changed")
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBAction func beginSearchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    declarationInfoController.fetchDeclarationInfo(with: searchBar.text!) { (declarationInfo) in
        if let declInfo = declarationInfo {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.fetchedDeclarationInfo = declInfo
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "declarationInfoSegue", sender: UIButton.self)
            }
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    alertController.addAction(tryAgainAction)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "declarationInfoSegue" else { return }
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DetailDeclarationInfoTableViewController
    destinationVC?.declarationInfo = fetchedDeclarationInfo
}

}
```

запрос на сервер

```
struct DeclarationInfoController {

func fetchDeclarationInfo (with searchConditions: String, completion: @escaping(DeclarationInfo?) -> Void) {
    var hostURL = "https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q="
    hostURL = hostURL + searchConditions

    let escapedSearchConditions = hostURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

    Alamofire.request(escapedSearchConditions!).responseString { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let text):
            if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
                print(data)
                do {
                    let declarationInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(DeclarationInfo.self, from: data)
                    completion(declarationInfo)
                } catch {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
// в этом месте нужно вставить код алерта, но я не знаю какой. помогите плиз
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    let declarationInfo: DeclarationInfo? = nil
                    completion(declarationInfo)
                    return
                }
            } else {
                print("bad JSON")
            }

        case .failure:
            print("fail")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А где метод запроса на сервер? Туда и надо вставлять алерт.

Comment: ок. метода запроса записан как функция fetchDeclarationInfo в структуре declarationInfoController. Отсутствие ответа ловится в print() в do-catch блоке. Какой должен быть синтаксис в теле функции, чтобы презентовать Алерт в контроллере, в котором эта функция будет вызвана

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блок в функции надо переписать.

```
func fetchDeclarationInfo (with searchConditions: String, completion: @escaping(_ info: DeclarationInfo?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)
```

`Error` напишите сами.
Например

```
enum error: Error {
        case bedResult
    }
```

если у вас все удачно, передавать `completion(declarationInfo, nil)`

Везде где принты с ошибкой:

```
print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
print("bad JSON")
print("fail")
```

Передавать `completion(nil, bedResult)`

Непосредственно в вашем контроллере, делайте проверку на наличие ошибки.

```
declarationInfoController.fetchDeclarationInfo(with: searchBar.text!) { (declarationInfo, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //Выводим алерт
        } else {
            //Показываем необходимые данные
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если `declarationInfo` приходит `nil` то показываете `alertController`

Попробуйте так:

```
@IBAction func beginSearchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    declarationInfoController.fetchDeclarationInfo(with: searchBar.text!) { [weak self] (declarationInfo) in
        if let declInfo = declarationInfo {
           self?.fetchedDeclarationInfo = declInfo
           self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "declarationInfoSegue", sender: UIButton.self)
        }
        else {
            self?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```